# Unit testing ASP .NET Core project with CLR 4.6.1 libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am having a hell of a time building an ASP .NET Core project running on CLR 4.6.1. It uses legacy CLR 4.6.1 libraries, which has been a massive problem. Because the .NET Core VS tooling can't deal with building the project properly, I've had to write build scripts that fix it up - the result being that VS can't build a working version of the project.

With this in mind, how can I unit test this? Ideally, I want a standalone test runner that can load a pre-compiled project, to avoid the test tooling having to build my main project.

I've tried both MSTest (it can't see the references to the SUT), and Xunit using `dotnet test` (which tries to build the project).

As requested, my (slightly sanitised) `project.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "System.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyLib.Common": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "MyLib.Integration": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "MyLib.Functions": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "MyLib.Numbers": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: UnitTesting works fine with ASP.NET Core which targets .net >=4.5 and I am not aware of any issues with it. Maybe you can post your project.json (and of class libraries if there are any involved) and see if we can fix your original issue

Comment: @Tseng By "Unit Testing" do you mean MS Test, i.e. the unit testing framework built into Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, but I use xunit with testrunner which runs inside Visual Studio. But you already mention that the .NET Core VS Tools have issues building it, so there may be something wrong with your project setup

Comment: Since you have a script to build your project, you can put it inside the `scripts` tag of your `project.json` (using precompile or postcompile for example). Then, you create a project for `xUnit` tests and configure the `project.json` in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't submit a comment due to reputation, have you tried the NUnit Test Runner? It comes as a standalone console application and takes the compiled test DLL name as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the links krlzlx, I will give them a read during my lunch hour. It seems my question has been set as the answer so I do hope I answered the question sufficiently for the asker.

Comment: Well I fell into your trap (your first line). Well done. I hope you'll get the right answers for users in need for  help in the future.

Comment: What "trap" of mine?

Comment: Your answer was on the "Very low quality" review queue and one of the action available is that the answer should have been a comment. And that's what you said in your fist line.

Comment: Ah, confusion cleared. Thanks again for the tips krlzlx